# How to set up a Private Wireless while using a Public network

Tags: wireless-networking

I will be going to a training course for a couple of months.  Where I will be staying offers wireless only.  They give out only one code per guest.  Is there any way to get a device to make a network that only I can use within my apartment.  It will be a pain to use only once device since I have a desktop, IPad, and Iphone. I will also be using a laptop uniil my Desktop arrives.

Answer (score 0):

One code per guest, doesn't mean one code per device.  Call them and find out, but usually it means they'll give you a key to the WiFi connection.

Comment: Sorry.  I should have wrote that better.  They were only giving out one code per room.  I will see if I can beg them for more.

Comment: @Dave Still, even if it is per room, doesn't mean it's per device...

Comment: From my experience it's usually just the WiFi password, which you can use for as many devices as you want.